# How to handle multiple messages from server websocket to front end client side?

Tags: javascript, arrays, websocket, socket.io

I'm developing a live chatting room application that supports around 1000 to 1200 users engaging in conversations within the same room. I'm utilizing socket.io to transmit messages from the clients to the server, which then broadcasts them back to all connected clients. However, I'm encountering performance issues when multiple users initiate chats simultaneously, resulting in a lag for the frontend users. Additionally, I have an event called "start_question" that allows users to select an answer. Unfortunately, when there are multiple ongoing chats, this event is displayed at different times for each user, leading to delays of 30 seconds to 1 minute in some cases. How can I improve the performance and synchronization of my application in scenarios where there are concurrent chat interactions and event triggers?

```
socket.on('user_chat', function (data){
    //append the message to an array
    userMessageArr.push(data);
})
// Check if userMessage is there then 
setInterval(function () {
    for (let i = 0; i < userMessageArr.length; i++) {
        //create html element to append to dom
       element.append += userMessageArr[i];
    }
    // append to dom
, 3000);
socket.on('user_chat', function (data){
    //display 
    showQuestion();
})
```

Comment: So you destroy and create all messages every time a new message is sent?

Comment: @Konrad No, i just append more messages to the DOM.